# Remove diacetyl taste with slurry

Tags: lagering, diacetyl-rest, pilsner

I have a Pilsner that I am currently lagering. It has a definite diacetyl taste. I may have flushed the yeast out too early and was too warm while fermenting. Can I add the trub from another beer that has finished fermenting to help remove the off taste?

Answer (score 2):

You want to add some actively fermenting beer.  There is a German technique called [Krausening](https://beerandbrewing.com/dictionary/oqdYkx8Usd/) for just this purpose.